# Query WordPress (REST) posts by the order they appear on the admin

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I am using the [Post Types Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/) plugin to re-order posts on WP Admin.

Is there a way to fetch WP REST API by that order?

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?orderby ??
```

WP Rest Api docs only shows order by:
date, id, include, title, slug

Answer (score 0):

Just omit `orderby` from the query and it will do it:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=20&page=1
```