# Ordering By Menu Order in the Wordpress REST API?

Tags: wordpress, sorting, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to display posts using the REST API and I want to display them in menu order based on how they are positioned in the admin menu.

I installed a plugin that allowed me to move posts to any position in the admin. I know querying the posts the normal way with wordpress there is a orderby: menu_order option, which would do what I am looking for, but I can't figure it out with the REST API.

My REST API looks like this:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/qd_leadership?_embed&per_page=100&orderby=menu_order
```

So I've tried that and that does not work. It says menu_order isn't an option. I also saw a post here:

[Query WordPress (REST) posts by the order they appear on the admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100699/query-wordpress-rest-posts-by-the-order-they-appear-on-the-admin)

That had a similar question. The only answer on that post is  to not have any orderby parameter and that should display them in the menu order, but that did not work for me. So I am stumped on how to order the posts from the REST API in menu order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its `bug` of wp core in rest api so you could use below hack for the solution.Please add below code in your active theme's `function.php`

```
add_filter( 'rest_post_collection_params', 'my_prefix_add_rest_orderby_params', 10, 1 );

function my_prefix_add_rest_orderby_params( $params ) {
    $params['orderby']['enum'][] = 'menu_order';

    return $params;
}
```

Tested and works.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to raju_eww for the hint in the right direction. But in case of a custom post type collection the filter hook name has to be like this:

```
add_filter( 'rest_custom-post-type_collection_params', 'my_prefix_add_rest_orderby_params', 10, 1 );
function my_prefix_add_rest_orderby_params( $params ) {
    $params['orderby']['enum'][] = 'menu_order';

    return $params;
}
```

found here:
https://www.timrosswebdevelopment.com/wordpress-rest-api-post-order/

Comment: I used this code for product post type and did not work! `rest_product_collection_params`

Comment: I used this code for product post type and did not work as default sort, but using `orderby=menu_order` query string it works. My filter hook is: `rest_product_collection_params`

Answer (score 2):

This is a more comprehensive solution that keeps you from adding this to every single post type that either exists natively or you have added to Wordpress.

```
add_filter( 'rest_endpoints', function( $endpoints ) {
    foreach ( $endpoints as $route => &$endpoint ) {
        foreach ( $endpoint as &$handler ) {
            if ( isset( $handler['args']['orderby'] ) ) {
                $handler['args']['orderby']['enum'][] = 'menu_order';
            }
        }
    }
    return $endpoints;
});
```

This code does the following:

1. Iterates over all registered REST API endpoints.
2. For each endpoint, it checks if there's an args array and specifically looks for the orderby argument within it.
3. If the orderby argument is found, it adds 'menu_order' to the enum array, which defines the allowed values for the orderby parameter.

By doing this, you're ensuring that 'menu_order' is an accepted value for the orderby parameter in all REST API endpoints where ordering is applicable, including your custom post types.

Place this code in your theme's functions.php file or in a custom plugin. This change should allow you to use orderby=menu_order in your REST API queries for any post type that supports it.

Comment: thank you this is confirmed working with woocommerce rest API in 2024 https://XXXX/wp-json/wc/v2/products/categories?parent=1067&exclude=15&per_page=99&page=1&hide_empty=true&_fields=id,name,slug,parent,count,lowest_price,has_children,count,lowest_price,image.src,menu_order&orderby=menu_order&consumer_key=XXXX&consumer_secret=XXXX

Answer (score -1):

Following code do sort by `menu_order` when `orderby` is not in query string (for woocommerce):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
function am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
    if(!$_GET['orderby']) {
    $args['orderby'] = 'menu_order';
    $args['order'] = 'asc';
    }
    return $args;
    }
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/mikejolley/1622323#gistcomment-1545997)